# Why does niO's selector selectedKeys removal seem not to work?

Tags: java, nio

After the server receives data for the first time, there will be data in each loop of selectedKeys. I would like to ask if the remove operation is not effective or there is some other reason

server code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8899));
    serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);//

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("start");
        selector.select();
        Iterator iter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iter.next();
            iter.remove();
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `selector`?

Comment: Your question would probably be easier to understand and answer with more pertinent code and explanation with details about the data, the code and your problem. Please check out the [ask] link.

Comment: VTR. There is nothing mysterious or unclear or incomplete about this question. @tgdavies Even before the edit it was obvious that `selector` was a `java.nio.channels.Selector`.

Comment: @OP You are selecting and finding ready keys, but you are never doing any I/O with them. So, they are ready again next time. If a key is readable you have to read from it, and if the read returned -1 you have to close the channel. If it is 'accept'-able you have to accept from it. And so forth.